# Enforce arbitrary function on C# generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create a generic function like this, which I plan to instantiate with basic types, mostly DateTime, int and string.

```
static T MyParameter<T>(string value, T defaultValue)
{
    return value.StartsWith("$$") ? defaultValue : T.Parse(value);
}
```

This won't compile as there is no guarantee that T will have "Parse".

Is there a "direct" way to implement it? (I mean, avoiding reflection or delegates to do the dirty work).

I can't find any constraint to T that would do the trick.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't.

Comment: My general approach to this is to constrain `T` to `IConverible`, and use `Convert.ChangeType` and cast to T to handle this. However, if your value starts with $$, it will almost always fail to parse unless you strip off the dollar signs.

Comment: @vcsjones I think that's why he returns `defaultValue` when `value` starts with `$$`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Oh, derp. I switched the condition in my head. Yes that makes good sense now.

Answer (score 6):

You could pass in the parse method for the generic case:

```
static T MyParameter<T>(string value, T defaultValue, Func<string, T> parse)
{
    return value.StartsWith("$$") ? defaultValue : parse(value);
}
```

But for convenience, you probably want to provide overloads for the most common types you plan to use:

```
static int MyParameter(string value, int defaultValue)
{
    return MyParameter(value, defaultValue, int.Parse);
}
static DateTime MyParameter(string value, DateTime defaultValue)
{
    return MyParameter(value, defaultValue, DateTime.Parse);
}
static string MyParameter(string value, string defaultValue)
{
    return MyParameter(value, defaultValue, x => x);
}
```

If you really don't like this, you could use reflection, though I wouldn't recommend it:

```
static T MyParameter<T>(string value, T defaultValue)
{
    if (value.StartsWith("$$"))
    {
        return defaultValue 
    }

    var method = typeof(T).GetMethod("Parse", new[] { typeof(string) });
    return (T)method.Invoke(null, new[] { value });
}
```

Comment: Note: Reflection can actually be a fair bit quicker if you cache `method` in a Dictionary per value of `T`.  (more time for validation getting the *right* method too)  Of course basic types all implement `IConvertible`.

Answer (score 2):

What about using a Constraint on the generic?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

So your method becomes:

```
static T MyParameter<T>(string value, T defaultValue) where T : IParseable
{
    return (T)(value.StartsWith("$$") ? defaultValue : defaultValue.Parse(value));
}
```

Of course this means that all types used must implement IParseable.

Comment: this is the correct approach. basically, you need to use covariance of the type to make sure that it conforms to what you are trying to call.

Comment: This won't actually compile. **1)** You're trying to call `Parse` statically on `T`, **2)** unless `IParseable` is generic (e.g. `where T : IParseable<T>`) there's no way the return value of `Parse` can be returned without a cast, and **3)** even if you fixed those issues, you still wouldn't be able to call this with built-in data types (`int`, `DateTime`, `string`) provided by .NET since they don't implement the custom `IParseable` interface.

Comment: Yep, you are right p.s.w.g.  I fixed #1 and #2.  #3, you are exactly right.  This is the problem with this code.  You basically have to write wrappers for all the basic data types which is annoying.

Comment: You still haven't fixed #2. If `IParseable` isn't a generic interface, it's return type will be something like `object`, so you'll have to cast it the return value to return it. If it is generic, you'd have to specify that in the constraint. Also, now that you've corrected #1, you have to deal with the possibility that `defaultValue` may be null. Sorry if it seems like I'm nit-picking. This is a valid approach, but I think without an working example, it's like to just cause more confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
static T MyParameter<T>(string value, T defaultValue)
{
    return (T) (value.StartsWith("$$") ? defaultValue : Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof (T)));
}
```